# What is this effect called? It has soft rectangular boxes

Tags: effects, texture, style-identification

I recently saw this pattern on a website that I really like. I am hoping to learn how to replicate this on my free time.
1) At the minimum, I need a name for patterns like this. I will google to see if there are lessons.
2) Even more helpful would be instructions on how to do so on gimp (preferred) or Photoshop. Inkscape or illustrations are fine too.

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: uh, what pattern? the very faint marks on it is a texture, looks like a paper texture to me. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a **subtle texture**. They were all the rage back in 2010-2013 when "artisan" styling, Victoriana and "skeumorphism" were in vogue, and everything looked like this:

[image]

Here's [an article from 2011](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/03/whys-hows-textures-web-design/) about what was then an exciting new trend...

You can find free-to-use things like this at http://subtlepatterns.com/ and http://www.transparenttextures.com/

To make them, look for tutorials on making **repeating patterns** in your favourite software. There are thousands of such tutorials, so just browse and find one that's close to what you want to do.

Comment: "artisan" styling and Victoriana are "out" now? Has design really become flavor of the week, where saying "that was so two years ago"  is actually relevant?

Comment: @Voxwoman Design is often a bit flavour of the week unfortunately... I wouldn't say that style is "out", it just seems not to be the new big thing or mainstream anymore. It's still quite widely used in appropriate contexts (craft products, historic themes, steampunk or hipster culture, etc) but it was 2010-2013 when it was at its peak and cropped up almost *everywhere*, even in contexts that didn't quite make sense (like random tech products, comms from mainstream brands and media startups)